# How to fix the coding

Tags: html, text, removable

My site is https://templatemonstrosity.blogspot.com/ . As you can see, on the very top of this page, there is an irritating text '-->'. I have searched through my entire XML do but I cannot find where it is, can someone please tell me what to do? If someone can please check out my template from https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw7OiqWvpt5sdXc3cUV5Y2ZMMVk and tell me which exact ine to fix, then it would be a big help.

Comment: Line 157 when I viewed the source of your page... `--></style>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's here (look in the source-code):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;margin: auto 0px;}}</style>
--></style>
```

Basically, you have multiple `<style>`-tags in the source, and here you have two ending tags, with a comment-bit in between - delete the second one. And...okay, I dunno Blogger, but if that is the standard, DAMN it's ugly code.

Comment: All I found was this @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;margin: auto 0px;}}</style>]]>

Comment: Might be the two `]]` on the end, unless they have a starting point somewhere. If it doesn't work to remove those, post more of the code - say 10 lines before that line, and 10 lines after as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I inspected your website, and right at the top of the body there is a "-->".  Getting rid of that worked for me.

step 1: look for this line/piece of code (I have not done html in forever).

right below that I see:

"-->
"

delete the "-->
".

You should be good to go.

Comment: I tried inspecting too, the problem is that I can't find where that is coming from.

Comment: This is my xml template https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw7OiqWvpt5sdXc3cUV5Y2ZMMVk